# Individual Auto Increment by Region in a SharePoint List Column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have requirement to have an auto increment list in SharePoint 2013. But the requirement is a bit odd.

I have regions like APAC, EMEA, US, AMERICAS. I want to add an incremented value for each region like the below.

APAC0001
APAC0002
APAC0003
EMEA0001
EMEA0002
EMEA0003
US0001
US0002
US0003

I would like to have this without any programming. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are regions maintained in separate list like master or its choice column ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible using SharePoint Designer Workflow. You can create a List Workflow for this and trigger it on Item Added